# UML Class Diagram tool for Javascript es2015 or TypeScript (forward and reverse engineering)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, uml, class-diagram

I've been looking all over the place and can't seem to find a UML Class Diagram tool for Javascript es2015 or TypeScript, doing forward and reverse engineering.
If anyone were so kind and knowlageable to instruct me in the right direction, they would earn my gratitude forever !
Best, M.